# Postgres query json path within array

Tags: json, postgresql

What would be the following expression to get the value `20` here?

```
SELECT ('{"a": [{"age":10}]}'::jsonb)->'a.*.age';
```

As the above currently gives me `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the paths, for example:

```
SELECT ('{"a": [{"age":10}]}'::jsonb)->'a' -> 0 -> 'age';
# 10
```